# Identifying true framerate of a video file using ffprobe/ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

As the header suggests I have a video file that seems to have been modified. When I call ffprobe and look at the timebase I see a 1/120 and get 120fps as the framerate. Let's say the video has 4000 frames according to the readout from ffprobe. When I manually click through each frame I see the frame number jumping by 200 frames vs going each individual frame. How can I filter this out and determine the actual framerate of the video file? I also run the freeze-detect command and can see there is "Frozen" frames but this isn't helping me narrow down the true framerate

Comment: The `avg_frame_rate` will in ffprobe is the effective rate.